# Duvida no Joomla

Tags: joomla

Boa tarde!
Estou com uma dúvida!
Estou começando agora nessa área, queria saber se é possivel instalar o Joomla em uma template minha. Exemplo: http://designprisma.com.br/. Quero utilizar o joomla somente para postar noticias nesse site. É possivel? Pois instalei o joomla no site, e ele cria um novo inves de aproveitar esse ai. Me ajudem!

Comment: No caso, acredito que tu deverás integrar teu html, tornando-o em template para assim usar o joomla nele. Mais prático usar o teu site, criar teu banco de dados para as notícias e integra-los. Sem CMS

Comment: Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Não usando o joomla, da maneira mais fácil, usando php e mysql

Comment: Vou tentar aqui